# How to prevent a svn user to avoid accessing other projects

Tags: apache, svn, ubuntu-16.04

**Environment:-**
OS:Ubundu 16.4
svn server version:1.9.3 (r1718519)

**Issue:-**

I have 2 projects in the svn and there are different access permissions for different users. I have updated the authuz file as below

```
[groups]

project1 = admin,user1,user2,user3
project2 = user4,user5

[/]
* = r
admin = rw
[project1:/]
@project1 = rw
admin = rw

[project2:/]
@project2 = rw
admin = rw
```

But still the user1 is able to checkout the project2 into his PC.(but he cannot commit changes). how to block this user1 from accessing the project2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[/]
* = r
```

This is your issue. `* = r` means all users are given read access. And since this command is underneath the `[/]` (or root) directory, that means they have read access to everything in the repository.

You have two options:

1. Remove the `* = r` line from underneath the root directory.
2. Underneath `[project2:/]` you can add a line that says `@project1 =`

With option #2, you have the ability to forbid certain users/groups from accessing a directory completely, however, doing this means they will still have access to any additional projects you may add to the repository and thus, you would need to continuously do option #2 for every project you add. I personally recommend option #1 and then only adding authenticated users to each project. Only admins should have root access in my opinion/experience.

Also, since you've added `admin = rw` underneath `[/]` you don't need to add `admin = rw` underneath any projects, because they inherently get read/write access to the entire repository.

Comment: Wow thanks for the answer. Issue solved. Simple mistake